# Shell script to test command line program

Tags: c, bash, scripting

I have a program written in C that operates similar to the below output.

```
WELCOME TO PROGRAM.

Hit 1 to do task 1.

Hit 2 to do task 2.

Hit q to quit.
```

What i need is a bash shell script that start the program, then enters 1, 2 and q into the program so i can test all the functionality in one command.

I would assume it to look similar to the following

```
#!/bin/bash

./start kernel 
1
2
q
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you use [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) for testing these types of applications.

Comment: The previously mentioned solutions appear to work in some cases, but yours seems to be the best solution. Thanks for the help byron :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a "here document" . The syntax looks like this:

```
./start kernel <<EOF
1
2
q
EOF
```

"EOF" can be whatever unique word you want, as long as it isn't something you'll actually need in the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can save your input in a text file - input.txt and execute your program this way: `./program < input.txt`

Comment: I call this method the "Poor Man's automation", and I use it way more often than I'd like to admit.  Zero error handling, but it usually gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
#! /bin/bash

printf "1\n2\nq\n" | ./start kernel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of shell scripts as what they are... just each line being executed in an (albeit new) shell.

A simple way to do this sort of input is, assuming `[your program]` accepts stdin, is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "1" | [your program] > [logfile1]
echo "2" | [your program] > [logfile2]
echo "q" | [your program] > [logfileq]
```

Comment: Forgive me if I have misunderstood; upon my original reading I thought you wanted to test these functionalities one at a time (what this code does), but it seems unclear now that I have read the other answers provided.

Comment: @whoever_voted_down... Since I'm new here could you please give me some tips on why you did that?